# Efficiently re-order a filtered subset of data relative to the unfiltered data

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

Let's say I have an array of animals, I then created a filtered subset of these animals as an array of quadrapeds (four-legged). I want to be able to re-order this subset by cuteness (via drag-and-drop). How can I efficiently update the order of the animals relative to each other?

JavaScript data structure example:

```js
class Animal {
    constructor(name, legCount, orderIndex) {
        this.name = name;
        this.legCount = legCount;
        this.orderIndex = orderIndex;
    }
}

var animals = [
    new Animal("dog", 4, 0),
    new Animal("cat", 4, 1),
    new Animal("snake", 0, 2),
    new Animal("mouse", 4, 3),
    new Animal("bird", 2, 4),
    new Animal("fish", 0, 5),
    new Animal("pig", 4, 6),
    new Animal("monkey", 2, 7),
    new Animal("spider", 8, 8),
    new Animal("horse", 4, 9),
];

var quadrapeds = animals.filter(animal => animal.legCount === 4);
```

I need to re-order the array in JavaScript, then POST through ASP.NET into an SQL Database and return the new array. The main problem is the performance when updating thousands of rows in the SQL Database just to adjust each `orderIndex`.

Is there maybe a way to update only the rows in the SQL Database that corelate to the filtered subset? Thus reducing the performance concerns.

Comment: How many animals have changed their `orderIndex`? Are they really thousands, or you are sending them all even if its `orderIndex` have not changed?

Comment: If the main performance problem is the database then most of those tags on your question don't belong/most the text is irrelevant; really it's about asking how to efficiently update a lot of rows. I'd recommend you supply an update query or a stored procedure with a table valued parameter that means you can write a single update that works in a set based way. Right now you're probably going through them RBAR style, updating one at a time. Make sure the where clause uses an index. Remember that you can add useless clauses to a where clause to encourage index use if you have one that could cover

Comment: Also look at your reordering strategy; if you're doing like `UPDATE t SET order = order+1 WHERE order > 9` and it updates 1000 rows (ie create a gap in the numbering, just so you can then update another row and set its order to 10), then consider that you don't need to because you downloaded 1000 animals, reshuffled so there are only 3 changed indexes, and so you can issue updates for just those 3; it doesn't matter that there are briefly two animals at index 10; by the end of the operation 3 updates occur, everything is in order and updates were minimal. Use a transaction if you want ACID

Comment: @JesúsLópez If I moved an entry from `orderIndex` 10,000 to 1, then would I not have to set the `orderIndex` of all 10,000?

Comment: @CaiusJard I included tags for all relevant parts of my stack because it's also a performance hit on JavaScript and potentially c# when running the re-order.

Comment: @pathurs. There are ways to not to update all 10000.  For example orderIndex could be decimal and just update 10000 to 0.5

Comment: @JesúsLópez I had thought of that, but at some point I'd have to fix the orderIndex before they hit a limit, I'd obviously rather not use a max varchar.

Comment: "At some point I'd have to fix the order index" - at some point in software engineering you have to fix everything. Everything is a compromise and good judgement of what is realistic is essential. "I used a GUID PK because one day this system is going to be so popular that I'll run out of ints faster than I can do something about it" doesn't happen in 99.9999% of cases, so burning megabytes of wasted space and hours of cpu time maintaining a solution that isn't fit for purpose, just so you can kick the can as impossibly far down the road as possible, isn't engineering a solution

Comment: This question needs more details to be answerable; what the use case is, what the existing strategy/code is, what the performance problem is, who makes the changes and how often.

Comment: @pathurs yes, at some point. Until that point you don't have any performance problem. When the point reaches reoder the set with a single update statement.

Comment: @pathurs . Use a bigint, then first 4 bytes for main ordering and the last 4 bytes for insertion. So how many insertions to the same place need to be done for you to need to rebuild the whole thing?

Comment: @JesúsLópez Thank you for the helpful comments, I'll try to incorporate your suggestions and see if it works.